# Can you make a shortcut to the compatibility troubleshooter? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

Something with some Windows update screwed up my Steam. I've literally tried everything to fix it, but the only thing that works is right clicking, properties, compatibility troubleshooter, launch in Windows 8 compatibility mode.

If I set it to that in the actual compatibility tab, it doesn't work. I have to launch it through the compatibility troubleshooter. I have no idea why this happens, but it just does.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to make a shortcut that will launch the troubleshooter without me having to right click and do all that stuff. Or better yet, a shortcut that just does exactly what the "test this program" button does when it launches Steam, whatever that may be. I'm just trying to eliminate some steps here.

Comment: While this can be answered (as the Answers show), you may wish to ask about your underlying problem. As far as I know, there isn't an uncompatibility with Steam and the latest Win 10, so there is likely something that could be done to fix this. Just because you've tried everything you can think of doesn't mean you've tried everything.

Comment: You've said you've tried everything. Does that include reinstalling Steam or reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you click the "Run compatibility troubleshooter" button, `pcwrun.exe` starts, generates an XML file, launches `msdt.exe` with the path to that file, and swiftly exits. To launch the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter for a specific program, pass the full path of the program's executable to `pcwrun.exe`. Assuming you're on a 64-bit machine, pasting this into the Create Shortcut window's path box will do the job:

```
pcwrun "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"
```

If your computer is 32-bit, remove the `(x86)` from the path to Steam.

Answer (score 2):

#### If there is a way to make a shortcut that will launch the troubleshooter?

Yes:

> 1. right-click on an empty area on your desktop.
> 2. Select New > Shortcut. In the first box of the Create Shortcut Wizard, copy-paste the following in the box:
>
>    ```
>    %systemroot%\system32\msdt.exe -id PCWDiagnostic
>    ```
>
>    [image]
> 3. Click Next.
> 4. Name the shortcut : Compatibility Shortcut and click Finish.
>
> Then select an appropriate icon for it.

Source [Create Program Compatibility Troubleshooter shortcut](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/program-compatibility-troubleshooter-desktop-shortcut)

Comment: So this is pretty close, but I need it to automatically be configured for using Steam if possible. It would be better than the whole thing I have to do right now but it does not have Steam under the programs list for some reason. Once again I don't know how feasible it is to automatically set it up to check for compatibility issues with Steam but I'm hopeful :o thanks for giving it a shot at least. I guess I wasn't as clear on that front as I should have been.

Comment: @CarterPrescott You might be able use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to automate your way though the rest of the steps...